# Cypress can't detect any elements on a particular site

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I've started using Cypress (v10.2.0) as an end to end testing framework and wanted to try out logging onto a banking site and filling the input fields.

However, when my Cypress opens https://www.anytimebanking.ulsterbank.co.uk with either Chrome (v102) or Edge (v102), it can't seem to find any site elements, the playground doesn't work and in addition throws a bunch of extension errors:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening as all the other sites I've tried work as expected, can find the page body and any other elements and don't throw any console errors.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Spec file is as follows:

```
describe('Online Banking spec', () => {
  it('opens the site', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.anytimebanking.ulsterbank.co.uk')
  })
})
```

Comment: It looks like that modal is blocking the rest of the site -- can Cypress get the elements in that modal?

Comment: Hi @agoff, nah the cypress can't seem to detect the modal window nor the two buttons. I've seen similar modal's pop up on other sites and Cypress seems to detect them well.

Comment: also the elements do not appear after manually removing the modal

Comment: What does the DOM look like in the dev console? Can you use the element selector to find elements?

Comment: Yeah I can get selectors though there, however, when I then try to cy.get('#selector I pull from the dev console') it says that it does not exist: `Expected to find element: #onetrust-accept-btn-handler, but never found it`.

Comment: Hi @kris, actually the modal window is contained inside an iframe whose id="ctl00_secframe". So you need to make use of iframe to close the Privacy window before moving to get the elements

Comment: Not just the modal, the entire app is an `<frame>` tag.

Comment: @Ankur thanks mate, checked how to deal with iframes and I can now select the elements! and as jjhelguero said the whole thing is an iframe so will need to keep that in mind when selecting stuff on that site

Comment: @Ankur happy to give you a correct answer if you decide to write an answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your entire app and the modal window is contained inside an iframe whose id="ctl00_secframe". So you need to make use of Iframe in cypress to close the Privacy window as well as to fetch other elements.

You can also refer : https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/